# Can I get an Anonymous ID per iCloud (per app/user, rather than per device)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I am so happy that I get an ID *per device*, so I can keep data per user anonymously with firebase! The only thing that could be better is if I could get an id per user's *iCloud* storage for the app.

I understand that how the authentication token is maintained per app, at least on the web, is that it is stored in local storage. It implies that a similar approach is being used per app in iOS in something like `UserDefaults`. I'm hoping there's an easy way to keep it instead in `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`.

#### edit with use case:

I have an app that is (with permission) capturing and anonymously collecting location data. I would like to have that data stored *per user* rather than *per device*, and I essentially can't use signed logins.
(actually, the reality is that I am **not** capturing that in firestore, I am capturing accompanying metric data from other apps designed to work with this one)

So *"why anonymous?"*, right? I am collecting time series data for third party apps - this presents risk of "use" to the user, and loss of control for that same data for the *subscriber apps* using the service I am writing.

Honestly, at a later point in time this might be converted to a library that allows apps to swarm their information together instead. But there are overhead concerns, and difficulty in trust for sharing data, with that approach and for my research project that approach is further from topic.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you describe it with other words, maybe in a use-case of what you want the users of your app to be able to do?

Comment: I think the difference would make sense if you were a bit more familiar with iOS and iCloud. UserDefaults is _per device_, while iCloud storage is _per user_ (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206504 ). this way, users with multiple devices can have a shared experience for an app they use on each.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen PS: sorry for my terse initial response. I know you :) Thanks for looking at my question!

Comment: I've added the use case

Comment: If you want a user to be able to access the same values from different devices, the user will need to identify themselves on those devices. That's not a use-case that anonymous authentication is made for. You'll need to use an identity provider that requires the user to actually sign in for that, just like they have to actually sign in to iCloud to get the sharing of settings between their devices.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if they identify their transactions non-anonymously, then the information that I am collecting is not anonymous. This is not a use case that allows for authenticated transactions. The anonymous mode is available for an unspecified duration, making it a prefect match. Can you answer my question about internals? How is does the device maintain the same anonymous connection for unspecifed durations?

Comment: for what it is worth if someone from google or .. anywhere else with a reference wanted to echo Frank's assertion that Firestore is intentionally not designed that way, Id close this ticket.